# TensorFlow model building

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was creating a basic Tensorflow deep learning model.
My Code is :-

```
# Creating the data 
x = np.array(\[-7.0,-4.0,-1.0,2.0,5.0,8.0,11.0,14.0])
y = np.array(\[3.0,6.0,9.0,12.0,15.0,18.0,21.0,24.0])

## Turning the data into tensors
x = tf.cast(tf.constant(x ), dtype = tf.float32)
y = tf.cast(tf.constant(y ), dtype = tf.float32)

x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis = 0)
```

My Model is :-

```
# Set the random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# Create a model 
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# Compile the model 
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
              metrics = ['accuracy']
              )

# Fitting the model 
model.fit(x,y, epochs = 5)
```

While predicting with the model, I wanted the model to make predictions but it gave error.

My prediction code is :-

```
model. Predict([17.0])
```

The Error is :-

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-914f309df50b> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.predict([17.0], dtype = tf.float32)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     63         filtered_tb = None
     64         try:
---> 65             return fn(*args, **kwargs)
     66         except Exception as e:
     67             filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)

TypeError: Model.predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

Answer (score 0):

While predicting the model in Tensorflow Keras API does not accept a dtype argumnet. So instead of this you need to pass your input data as a Numpy array. Please find the below code, I have tried this code. we wont get any errors.

```
# Creating the data 
x = np.array(\[-7.0,-4.0,-1.0,2.0,5.0,8.0,11.0,14.0])
y = np.array(\[3.0,6.0,9.0,12.0,15.0,18.0,21.0,24.0])

## Turning the data into tensors
x = tf.cast(tf.constant(x ), dtype = tf.float32)
y = tf.cast(tf.constant(y ), dtype = tf.float32)

x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis = 0)


# Set the random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# Create a model 
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# Compile the model 
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.mae,
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the model 
model.fit(x,y, epochs = 5)
 
# Model Predict
prediction = model.predict(np.array([17.0]))
print(prediction)
```